# Rstudio update cause Rcpp fail to compile

Tags: c++, r, xcode, compiler-errors, rcpp

I recently updated my Rstudio to V2022.07.2+576, but found Rcpp can no longer compile code.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int add(int x, int y, int z) {
  int sum = x + y + z;
  return sum;
}')
```

, which give me error message like:

```
clang-12: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
In file included from file7898532e8a3d.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:10: fatal error: 'cmath' file not found
#include <cmath>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf:176: file7898532e8a3d.o] Error 1
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/private/var/folders/0l/_zb89yxd4qs6g7t3dx2t__k80000gr/T/RtmpPHmvlY/sourceCpp-aarch64-apple-darwin20-1.0.9" -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c file7898532e8a3d.cpp -o file7898532e8a3d.o
 Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir, : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

I tried to reinstall R/Rstudio, and update Xcode, but had no good luck. Here is my sessioninfo

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_1.0.9        MASS_7.3-58.1     doParallel_1.0.17 iterators_1.0.14  foreach_1.5.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] xfun_0.31              tidyselect_1.1.2       purrr_0.3.4            splines_4.2.2          operator.tools_1.6.3  
 [6] lattice_0.20-45        vctrs_0.4.1            generics_0.1.3         htmltools_0.5.3        GWASExactHW_1.01      
[11] stats4_4.2.2           yaml_2.3.5             mgcv_1.8-41            utf8_1.2.2             rlang_1.0.4           
[16] pillar_1.8.0           glue_1.6.2             withr_2.5.0            DBI_1.1.3              BiocGenerics_0.42.0   
[21] gdsfmt_1.32.0          GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.8 lifecycle_1.0.1        zlibbioc_1.42.0        Biostrings_2.64.0     
[26] codetools_0.2-18       evaluate_0.15          Biobase_2.56.0         knitr_1.39             SeqArray_1.36.2       
[31] IRanges_2.30.0         fastmap_1.1.0          GenomeInfoDb_1.32.2    fansi_1.0.3            broom_1.0.0           
[36] backports_1.4.1        S4Vectors_0.34.0       XVector_0.36.0         digest_0.6.29          formula.tools_1.7.1   
[41] dplyr_1.0.9            GenomicRanges_1.48.0   grid_4.2.2             cli_3.3.0              tools_4.2.2           
[46] bitops_1.0-7           magrittr_2.0.3         RCurl_1.98-1.7         tibble_3.1.8           mice_3.14.0           
[51] crayon_1.5.1           tidyr_1.2.0            pkgconfig_2.0.3        Matrix_1.5-1           data.table_1.14.2     
[56] assertthat_0.2.1       rmarkdown_2.14         rstudioapi_0.13        logistf_1.24.1         R6_2.5.1              
[61] SeqVarTools_1.34.0     nlme_3.1-160           compiler_4.2.2
```

Comment: Did you change your R version or install any packages when updating RStudio? Do you have an `.Rprofile` file in your home directory that configures any options? Does it work if you run though R directory rather than using RStudio?

Comment: That seems to be a fight between you and macOS; I cannot help as I work on Linux. In case you get no actionable help here please consider the r-sig-mac mailing list for macOS specific help.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the comments. Yes, I tried to run the code in R instead of Rstudio, and it compiled successfully.

Comment: I reinstalled the older version of Rstudio (2022.02.4+500), and it worked again.

Comment: If you have a reproducible example, then it may be a good idea to report the error the rstudio team: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: I have the same problem but for me it is not linked to rstudio, the problem also appears when running directly on terminal.